# Проблемы с выводом из бд

Tags: python, sql, discord, бот, sqlite3

Делаю бота для дискорда и столкнулся с проблемой вывода из бд значений с таблицы в эмбет дискорда, то есть выводит у меня [(1,)], а нужно просто цифру

```
async def boss(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    author = ctx.message.author
    emb = discord.Embed(title ='**КЛАНОВАЯ ИГРА**', description = '**КРАТОСС**', colour = discord.Color.purple())

    emb.add_field(name = 'Уровень:', value = cur.execute(f'SELECT lvl FROM DiscordBossData WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}').fetchmany(), inline= False)
```

Выводит:
КЛАНОВАЯ ИГРА
КРАТОСС
Уровень:
[(1,)]
А нужно:
КЛАНОВАЯ ИГРА
КРАТОСС
Уровень:
1

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете `.fetchmany()`, этот метод нужен для возврата списка записей, а записями будут кортежи (в вашем случае на 1 элемент `lvl`):

```
emb.add_field(name = 'Уровень:', value = cur.execute(f'SELECT lvl FROM DiscordBossData WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}').fetchmany(), inline= False)
```

Вам нужно использовать метод `fetchone`:

```
result = cur.execute(f'SELECT lvl FROM DiscordBossData WHERE userid = {ctx.author.id}').fetchone()
emb.add_field(name='Уровень:', value=result[0], inline=False)
```

---

**PS.**

Не рекомендую передавать параметры явно в строку запроса, а использовать биндинги (bindings), это упрощает запрос при куче параметров и избавляет от возможных sql-инъекций:

```
result = cur.execute('SELECT lvl FROM DiscordBossData WHERE userid=?', [ctx.author.id]).fetchone()
```

Comment: оаоаоа, я очень сильно благодарю тебя, я использовал и fetchone, и даже в переменную записывал, но никак не мог избавиться от скобок и запятых. Большое спасибо <3

Comment: @Артур, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)